# Drawables in Preferences are displayed small

Tags: android, android-preferences

In my app, I download user photo images and I assign has the icon of a preference.

The downloaded image size is 100x100px

but sometimes, when I assign to a preference icon, it is displayed super-small and I don't know why.

Is possible to display in normal size?

In other parts of my app, when I assign the drawable to a ImageView is displayed correctly.

Thanks

[image: screenshow]

Comment: what height and width you gave to you imageview

Comment: You can show your layout (xml) about icon imageview to get more support with detail. And you can try my resolve: set min layout_with/height of ImageView (profile icon) to 100x100 and max from you want. And set android:scale_type = "fit_xy" (or try other to fit)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Is a Preference, I assign with preference.setIcon. Not a ImageView here. The downloaded image size is 100x100px

Comment: Exactly same issue here.